# store svg paths in json for fabric.js

Tags: svg, cufon, fabricjs

**Cufon** is gone from fabric, but i want to use a custom font.
I converted the **ttf to svg** with batic, then i parsed the svg and stored the paths in a JSON.
The idea is to use this paths to build a text in fabric.

my JSON looks like this:

```
 {" ":{"d":"","horiz-adv-x":"467"},"!":{"d":"M210 378L150 1122V1466H399V1122L340 378H210ZM160 0V281H390V0H160Z","horiz-adv-x":"559"},"\"":{"d":"M135 945L92 1218V1466H343V1...
```

as u can see i use the characters as key. the problem i want to access to the exclamation mark font.! wont work.

PS.: maybe this big hassle is for nothing, and i could access to the cufon generated paths through cufon, and use it in fabric. but as far as i can remember fabric's path wont take cufon's path.

Comment: You can use custom font by including woff/svg file in a document — the same way you would use it with HTML/CSS.